# Price Set: Update quantity based on selection?

Tags: price-sets

We have a pricing structure where a standard membership is $15/year and membership for an additional member of the household is $10/year.

I'd like to automatically update the "nubmer of additional members in household" field so the price per unit is multiplied by the number of years selected in the "Standard Memberships" field.

For example, if a user selects 1 year standard and 1 household member, the household member would be $10.  2 years standard and 1 household member, that household member would be $20.

[image: Price Set Example]

Comment: It would also be nice if I could ask for the names of the additional household members, and automatically have contacts created.

Comment: Hi Dave, if you mention your cms you may get some suggestions for workaround using eg Drupal Webform or WP Caldera in case you want to avoid a coding solution - or are you happy with jscript type suggestions?

Comment: I'm open to any and all options.  This is Wordpress... and I am competent with JavaScript and PHP.  Caldera Forms might be the easy way out though. Still, I'm interested to hear your other solutions.

Comment: So I played with Caldera Forms.  Looks like I can do what I want, but the cost of the Stripe plugin is more than our small club wants to spend.  I've been able to do simple things with jquery/javascript, like change labels and things.  I'm trying to figure out how to add line items, etc.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: i don't think you would be paying for the stripe plugin - you would use the integration available between caldera and civicrm and use your civi payment processor

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way: "Note: This processor does not process payment transactions on it's own, it just creates a Contribution in CiviCRM with single or multiple line items. In order to process live payment transaction, a Caldera Forms add-on is needed. Currently this processor intergrates with Caldera Forms' Stripe and Authorize.net add-ons for single/one-off payments."

Comment: thx for correcting me. hopefully a js guru might come along and help figure out how to do this

Comment: I've got a "quick and dirty" solution working, based on the "percentage price field" plugin. I changed it to simply add the proper stuff rather than doing its normal job.  Dirty, for sure, but it works.  Eventually I plan to fix it up and then contribute back to the project.

Comment: you may as well add that comment as an Answer and Accept it.